# Graphite will only display data for the past 24 hours

Tags: graphite

Here's the display for a stat for the past 24 hours (in Graphite Composer):

[image: Past 24 hours]

Here's the display for a stat for the "past 14 days":

[image]

Not much difference there. I cannot convince Graphite to display any data for any period past the past 24 hours.

Here are the relavent entries from `storage-schemas.conf` (I'm using StatsD):

```
[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974

[stats_counts]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974
```

and my `storage-aggregation.conf`:

```
[min]
pattern = \.min$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.max$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = average
```

I have five or so days of data captured so far. What am I missing?

**EDITED to add:**

I guess I should mention that I started out with the default `storage-schemas.conf` and only yesterday rebuilt my whisper database files to match the above configuration. I don't think this should be relevant, but there it is.

**UPDATED:**

I'm using 0.9.10 of graphite-web and whisper, from PyPI, released in May 2012.

Comment: Seems like UI issue in the Graphite Web App, did you solve it eventually? I would just do a referesh to the page... Notice that if you don't have information in Whisper in your 14 days period then the graph still have to show that period but with no "lines" in the graph...

Comment: Strange. It was briefly showing periods longer than 24 hours, and now it's back to only 24 hours. It's got to be a bug.

Comment: What versions of carbon & graphite are you running? We're seeing the same problem - some graphs exhibit it, others don't.

Comment: Both are at 0.9.10, the latest release on PyPI.

Comment: The storage schema is only read when whisper files are first created. If you changed it, you'd need to rebuild or delete the existing ones. Noticed you rebuilt them - did that fix your problem, or still the same thing?

Comment: Rebuilding did not seem to address the issue. Perhaps I should rebuild them again?

Comment: Or just delete them to be sure

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, this is what I get for not pasting the entire configuration. Here's what it *actually* looked like:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d

[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974

[stats_counts]
pattern = ^stats_counts.*
retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974
```

Of course, the `[default_1min_for_1day]` section was matching first, ahead of the other two, and so I was only getting data for the past 24 hours. Moving the catch-all to the end of the file seems to have addressed the issue.

Comment: I have been looking for help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433697/graphite-returning-incorrect-datapoint

Comment: @David Eyk, I am facing something similar and cannot figure out what the problem is. I am trying to get hourly avg for month worth of data. Rather than getting hourly, I get 2 hours avg data. Any ideas what I might be doing?

Comment: @user1471980 Hard to say without seeing your config. I recommend asking a new question, and including a detailed description of what you're trying to do and your configuration.

Comment: @DavidEyk, what configuration your're refering to? /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py?

Comment: @DavidEyk, I did ask this question, but not getting any response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396297/how-do-you-get-hourly-avg-from-graphite-for-the-last-30-days

Comment: David, what is your retention actualy doing? `retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974`

Comment: No idea. :) I think it was a default thing, but I don't remember. I'm afraid the server I had graphite on melted down pretty thoroughly a few years ago, and I haven't bothered to give graphite another try.