# Graphite Carbon only shows metrics for the last 24 hours

Tags: metrics, graphite, grafana, graphite-carbon

There is a similar question here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030063/graphite-will-only-display-data-for-the-past-24-hours)
although my problem is not the same.

**/etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf**

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[test]
pattern = ^test\.
retentions = 1h:100d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

send metric:

**Works:**
`echo test.count 145.0`date -d 2017-04-29T22:34:35 +"%s"`| nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003`

**Does not Work:** (more than 24h ago) 
`` echo test.count 145.0 `date -d 2017-04-28T22:34:35 +"%s"` | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003 ``

**whisper-fetch:** `whisper-fetch --pretty --from=1483261475 /var/lib/graphite/whisper/test/count.wsp`

*1483261475 : *this is the timestamp for 1/1/2017*

```
Fri Apr 28 21:00:00 2017    None
Fri Apr 28 22:00:00 2017    None
Fri Apr 28 23:00:00 2017    None
...
Sat Apr 29 16:00:00 2017    None
Sat Apr 29 17:00:00 2017    None
Sat Apr 29 18:00:00 2017    None
Sat Apr 29 19:00:00 2017    None
Sat Apr 29 20:00:00 2017    1000.000000
Sat Apr 29 21:00:00 2017    None
Sat Apr 29 22:00:00 2017    145.000000
Sat Apr 29 23:00:00 2017    None
```

**whisper-info**: `whisper-info /var/lib/graphite/whisper/test/count.wsp`

```
maxRetention: 8640000
xFilesFactor: 0.0
aggregationMethod: sum
fileSize: 28828

Archive 0
retention: 8640000
secondsPerPoint: 3600
points: 2400
size: 28800
offset: 28
```

now, if I use another section and set the **retentions** to:
`retentions = 10:2160,60:10080,600:262974`

then it works, I am able to see metrics for different dates, what might be going on here?

What services should be restarted or how to clean/reset the whisper DB?

Comment: Not sure what's your problem here...
You're sending 1 point to test.count, getting that point back. What's the question?

Comment: I send them in 2 different days, problem is that it only takes the point for the last 24 hours

Comment: Ah, sorry, was blind. Did you test this metric in Graphite? It has a cache which can be flushed on disk much later.

Comment: Yes, graphite also don't show the metrics. how to flush the cache? I have used `whisper-resize` but did not seem to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Graphite should show metrics, otherwise, it's something else. Sorry, then I ran out of ideas. If metrics are coming - they should be in Graphite.